# express-validator 5.3.1 to 6.6.0 expressValidator is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to update  express-validator 5.3.1 to 6.6.0. I got a lot of confused with the documentation. I tried to update my code without a sucess. I have an error expressValidator is not a function or req.check is not a funtion . I know the legacy api is gone but I want to update to 6.6.0. Can you help me because I have no clue. I tried req.checkBody or req.body , still is not a function. Thank you

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const expressValidator = require("express-validator");


require('dotenv').config();

// import routes
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

//app
const app = express();

//db connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useCreateIndex:true
}).then(() => console.log('Database Connected'));

//middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressValidator());

//routes middleware
app.use("/api",userRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
});
```

/validator/index.js

```
exports.userSignupValidator = (req, res, next) => {
    req.check('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('email', 'Email must be between 3 to 32 characters')
        .matches(/.+\@.+\..+/)
        .withMessage('Email must contain @')
        .isLength({
            min: 4, max: 32
        });
    req.check('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('password').isLength({min: 6})
        .withMessage('Password must contain at least 6 characters')
        .matches(/\d/)
        .withMessage('Password must contain a number');
        const errors = req.validationErrors()
        if(errors) {
            const firstError = errors.map(error => error.msg)[0]
            return res.status(400).json({error: firstError});
        }
        next();
};
```

routes/user.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const {signup} = require("../controllers/user");

const {userSignupValidator} = require('../validator');

router.post("/signup", userSignupValidator, signup);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

1. app.js --> Remove all the instances of express-validator. That means you do not need to import it here neither you have to use it as middleware so remove `const expressValidator = require("express-validator");` and `app.use(expressValidator());`
2. /validator/index.js -->
   import check from express-validator here in this file.
   `const { check } = require('express-validator');`. Use `check` instead of `req.check`.
3. signup controller -->
   Inside your signup controller use `const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');` to get validation result.

To get a better picture you can visit my repository https://github.com/sprakash57/Contrivocial

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working verfy welll :) thanks a lot.

Comment: @SergioA Happy to help. If the answer really helped you please upvote it.